# Using a pipeline variable for a variable group in YAML?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would like to use a common pipeline definition for our solutions. Using variables, I would like to specify solution specific settings. This works, except for a variable group.

I would like to use the pipeline definition in my variable group definition.
For example:

> - group: $(Build.DefinitionName).Dev

But that does not work. Another option would be to use a pipeline variable, but neither does work:

> - group: $(buildDefinitonName).Dev
> - group: {{ variables.buildDefinitonName }}.Dev

What does work is a parameter, but I do not want to specify it for each run.

> - group: ${{ parameters.buildDefinition }}.Dev

Comment: Have you checked the following reply? Is it solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use your deployment in a template and scope the variable group to a job in that template. The parameter passed into the template would be the environment.

Here is how the template could look:

```
  jobs:
  - deployment:  Deploy_JobName
    variables:
    - group: 'ProjectName${{ parameters.stage}}'
```

The parameter in the template would look like:

```
parameters:
- name: stage
  type: string
```

This template would be called from a joblike:

```
jobs:
  - template: template.yml
    parameters:
      stage: ${{ parameters.stage }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your response. Found out that

- group: ${{ variables['Build.Definition'] }}.Dev

also works. So you can use predefined variables, but not pipeline variables this way.